# Combining results of different count(*) sql queries

Tags: sql-server

i wrote a query for retrieving data from microsoft sql server database. the objective was to count the number of bills with pictures and total number of bills in an area represented by subdivision the query i wrote works fine but it takes alot of time to fetch results. on normal pc it takes about 4-5 minutes however on pc with higher ram it takes under a minute. since i'm not an expert of sql i need help in optimization of my query if possible. here is the query please let me know if it can be further optimized.

```
SELECT [sub division], 
       [total bills], 
       [pic bills], 
       ( ( t1.[pic bills] * 100 ) / t2.[total bills] ) AS '%' 
FROM   (SELECT gbsdiv   AS 'Sub Division', 
               Count(*) AS 'Pic Bills' 
        FROM   tblgbmain 
        WHERE  ( gbpicture1 IS NOT NULL 
                  OR gbpicture2 IS NOT NULL ) 
               AND gbbatch = 15 
        GROUP  BY gbsdiv) t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT gbsdiv   AS 'Sub Division1', 
                          Count(*) AS 'Total Bills' 
                   FROM   tblgbmain 
                   WHERE  gbsdiv IN (SELECT gbsdiv 
                                     FROM   tblgbmain 
                                     WHERE  ( gbpicture1 IS NOT NULL 
                                               OR gbpicture2 IS NOT NULL ) 
                                            AND gbbatch = 15 
                                     GROUP  BY gbsdiv) 
                          AND gbbatch = 15 
                   GROUP  BY gbsdiv) t2 
               ON t1.[sub division] = t2.[sub division1]
```

[image: this is the output of the query which was needed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to store interim results into indexed tables:

```
declare @PicBills table (
    SubDivision     int not null primary key clustered,
    PicBillsCount   int not null
)

declare @TotalBills table (
    SubDivision     int not null primary key clustered,
    TotalBillsCount int not null
)

insert into @PicBills
select 
    gbsdiv ,
    count(*)
from   
    tblgbmain 
where  
    ( gbpicture1 is not null or gbpicture2 is not null ) and gbbatch = 15 
group by 
    gbsdiv;


insert into @TotalBills
select 
    gbsdiv ,
    count(*)
from   
    @PicBills pb
    inner join tblgbmain on gbsdiv = SubDivision
where  
    gbbatch = 15 
group by 
    gbsdiv;

select 
    [sub division]  =   t1.SubDivision  , 
    [total bills]   =   TotalBillsCount , 
    [pic bills]     =   PicBillsCount   , 
    [%]             =   PicBillsCount * 100 / TotalBillsCount  
from   
    @PicBills t1 
    inner join @TotalBills t2 on t1.SubDivision = t2.SubDivision;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes breaking the queries will also give you better performance. Also check the what execuion plan says and create the missing index.

Most likely you may have to create a `non clustered` index on `gbbatch, gbpicture1, gbpicture2` including `gbsdiv` as covering index

```
SELECT gbsdiv   AS 'Sub Division', 
       Count(*) AS 'Pic Bills' 
INTO   #temp 
FROM   tblgbmain 
WHERE  ( gbpicture1 IS NOT NULL 
          OR gbpicture2 IS NOT NULL ) 
       AND gbbatch = 15 
GROUP  BY gbsdiv 

SELECT t1.[sub division], 
       [total bills], 
       [pic bills], 
       ( ( t1.[pic bills] * 100 ) / t2.[total bills] ) AS '%' 
FROM   #temp t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT gbsdiv   AS 'Sub Division1', 
                          Count(*) AS 'Total Bills' 
                   FROM   tblgbmain t 
                   WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                  FROM   #temp te 
                                  WHERE  t.gbsdiv = te.[Sub Division])
                   Group by gbsdiv ) t2 
               ON t1.[sub division] = t2.[sub division1]
```

Comment: i'm not familiar with some of the terms you used in this code but the te.gbsdiv in second last line of the code is not working. gbsdiv is not being accessed through te

Comment: and if i change that to te.[sub division] then this error is resolved but another error comes on line 15
'Column 'tblgbmain.gbSdiv' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

Comment: @Atif - Updated check now

Comment: the query takes less time to execute but the results are all wrong. :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a CTE will help to speed up the overall query? Something like:

```
WITH t1 AS (
 SELECT gbsdiv   AS 'Sub Division', 
        Count(*) AS 'Pic Bills' 
        FROM   tblgbmain 
        WHERE  ( gbpicture1 IS NOT NULL 
              OR gbpicture2 IS NOT NULL ) 
        AND gbbatch = 15 
        GROUP  BY gbsdiv
)
SELECT [Sub Division], 
       [total bills], 
       [pic bills], 
       ( ( [pic bills] * 100 ) / [total bills] ) AS '%' 
FROM  t1 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT gbsdiv   AS 'Sub Division1', 
         Count(*) AS 'Total Bills' 
  FROM   tblgbmain 
  WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE gbsdiv=[Sub Division] )
  AND gbbatch = 15
  GROUP BY gbsdiv ) AS t2
ON [Sub Division] = [Sub Division1]
```

There is a little DEMO with stackexchange data (appr. 4.7 million records) [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/350376/collects-counts).